# How to handle simultaneous user fling and programmatic scroll in Android ScrollView

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-scrollview

I have a `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView`. The `LinearLayout` has 100 `FrameLayouts`. When a button is clicked I insert new `FrameLayout`s in an in-between position from a  `BackgroundWorker`. In order to maintain the position of the currently viewed `FrameLayout` I scroll the `ScrollView` to the offset that is equal to the current offset plus the height of the newly inserted `FrameLayout`.

While this process is running in the `BackgroundWorker` if the user flings the contents of the ScrollView with a positive velocity the same `FrameLayout` is coming again and again. For instance you start flinging with a small velocity from `FrameLayout` numbered 7, 8 appears from bottom but before appears fully again 7 comes. User scroll also works fine. The problem is with only fling.

I found that while flinging, in the `OnScrollChanged` event the `oldt` parameter is greater than `t` which is unexpected because the fling velocity is positive.

Below I insert new `FrameLayouts` from the 5th, 6th, 7th, 8th,.... positions in order.

```
public class MainActivity : Activity {
    ScrollView1 sV;
    Button btn;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    BackgroundWorker worker;
    Handler handler;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        sV = FindViewById<ScrollView1>(Resource.Id.scrollView1);
        btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.pagedownbutton);
        btn.Click += Btn_Click;
        sV.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);

        linearLayout = new LinearLayout(ApplicationContext);
        linearLayout.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;

        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;
        handler = new Handler();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            TextView txt = new TextView(ApplicationContext);
            txt.Text = i.ToString();
            txt.TextSize = 50;
            txt.SetTextColor(Color.White);
            txt.Gravity = Android.Views.GravityFlags.Center;
            FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(ApplicationContext);
            frameLayout.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Blue);
            frameLayout.AddView(txt);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(700, 1200);
            layoutParams.SetMargins(0, 5, 0, 0);
            layoutParams.Gravity = Android.Views.GravityFlags.Center;
            frameLayout.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
            linearLayout.AddView(frameLayout, i);
        }

        sV.AddView(linearLayout);

    }

    private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            TextView txt = new TextView(ApplicationContext);
            txt.Text = "i" + i.ToString();
            txt.TextSize = 50;
            txt.SetTextColor(Color.White);
            txt.Gravity = Android.Views.GravityFlags.Center;

            FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(ApplicationContext);
            frameLayout.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Blue);
            frameLayout.AddView(txt);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(700, 1200);
            layoutParams.SetMargins(0, 5, 0, 0);
            layoutParams.Gravity = Android.Views.GravityFlags.Center;
            frameLayout.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;

            //Inducing some delay so that the background process will run long

            for (int j = 0; j < 10000000; j++) {

            }

            //Adding FrameLayout and scrolling

            handler.Post(() => {
                linearLayout.AddView(frameLayout, 5 + i);

                if (sV.ScrollY >= (5 + i) * 1205)
                sV.ScrollTo(0, 1205 + sV.ScrollY);
            });
        }
    }

    private void Btn_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();            
    }
}





public class ScrollView1 : ScrollView{
    public ScrollView1(Context context):base(context) {

    }

    public ScrollView1(Android.Content.Context context, Android.Util.IAttributeSet attr) : base(context, attr) {

    }
    protected override void OnScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {

    }

    public override void Fling(int velocityY) {
        base.Fling(velocityY);
    }
}
```

How can I make the `FrameLayout`s appear in order without scroll malfunctions while flinging with the programmatic scroll takes place in a background thread?

Comment: Why `FrameLayout` 7 appears twice or maybe more times (it depends on user's operation)， it is because that your BackgroundWorker creats a `FrameLayout` and posts it to your UI thread ,and then your UI thread renders it to your phone screen while you slide up to 8, it is at this time.

Comment: Why you don't use `ListView` or `RecyclerView`?